# How to find the exact exception without ControllerAdvice in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-restcontroller

I'm working on a Spring Boot project at the Rest Controller, and I need some help regarding how to send an exception to the client in a REST API.

So, I have this type of code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users")
public Users getUsers() { 
   service.getUsers();
}
```

I want to do an implementation and if there is an error send an email to an admin. I can't use ResponseEntity or ControllerAdvice. I just want to use a try-catch, can I catch the Exception and then inside the catch to find the exact exception and throw it, or should I catch the exact exception and how can I make it?

```
try {
   service.getUsers();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // implementation to send the email
   throw new NotFoundException or BadException, etc
}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: You can do whatever java let you. In particular, catch an exception an throw another one. However, random exception with end with 500 response code by default. What's the final goal, response with specific code/body??

Comment: you should be use multiple catch statements and then in your specific exception send email https://www.javatpoint.com/multiple-catch-block-in-java